# Startup Rack server without config.ru?

Tags: ruby, config, rack

I've been messing with Rack a lot lately, and am wondering how you could startup a Rack server by running a file (e.g. `app.rb`) without the use of `config.ru`. Is this possible, or is it a more complex method?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the built-in WEBrick server instead. So where you might normally have something like this:

```
# app.rb
class App
  def call(env)
    return [200, {"Content-Type" => "text/html"}, "Hello, World!"]
  end
end

# config.ru
require 'app'
run App.new
```

You can instead consolidate it and just run `ruby app.rb` directly:

```
#app.rb
class App
  def call(env)
    return [200, {"Content-Type" => "text/html"}, "Hello, World!"]
  end
end

Rack::Handler::WEBrick.run(App.new, :Port => 9292)
```

Comment: Thanks, however I've started using something more like `Rack::Server.start(...)` rather than a pure WEBBrick server (allowing you to use thin as well). Thanks for the tip!